# 12.04 - How to update ALSA driver to 1.0.25

Tags: drivers, sound, alsa

I have a relatively new Intel "Ultrabook", the HP Envy Spectre XT. It has the IDT 92HD99 sound card. Support for this was added to ALSA 1.0.25 based on this changelog:

http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php?title=Changes_v1.0.24_v1.0.25&action=edit

However the ALSA driver version in Ubuntu 12.04 is 1.0.24. Can someone explain how to update the ALSA driver to 1.0.25? The alsa-base package says it's using a package version 1.0.25-dfsg-0ubuntu1.

Here is my ALSA version info:

!!ALSA Version
!!------------

Driver version:     1.0.24
Library version:    1.0.25
Utilities version:  1.0.25

I think I need to get that "Driver version" up to 1.0.25 to get support for my hardware. Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A solution will be to use the ppa `ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa`.
It description says

> This PPA will be used to provide testing versions of packages for
>   supported Ubuntu releases.

It contains `ALSA 1.0.25 driver` package for precise(12.04).
**N.B:** I haven't tested it, so please be careful.

Answer (score 0):

I can see the question is pretty out of date, but could this help you?

http://hometheatersalsa.com/updated-alsa-drivers/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Ubuntu precise LTS is having the ALSA version of 1.0.24. 
You can look at the below link, where the upgrade script has been attached. 
I have tried on the AMD's new SI products and it worked well.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1681577

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.